reduce 12V to 1.5V for voltage analysis
I need to analyze the state of a 12-volt voltage rail with a microcontroller. The test will be done on the voltage rail without load. The microcontroller operates at 3.3 volts. How can I do this?
I thought about using an operational amplifier to divide the voltage, but it would be an inverting amplifier, so I would have to build another inverter to get the correct voltage. I thought it would be very complex. I also thought about using a simple voltage divider with resistors, but I have my doubts about whether that would be the best choice.
What do you suggest as the correct choice?

"but it would be an inverting amplifier, so I would have to build another inverter to get the correct voltage." Well You can calc the inverse in SW... just as a hint. You just need a stable known ref voltage for the AD Converter

"Best" is the enemy of "good enough".  What problems do you  see the voltage divider causing?

I personally don't see a problem with the resistive divider, but I was told that it wasn't a good choice. I think that in this circuit it's not even a problem, I just want to be sure of the choice.

@Delfino0 What was said about the voltage divider? What are you wishing to accomplish other than getting from 12V to 1.5V? Having voltage divider versus an LDO versus  a buck converter, etc. has its own advantages and disadvantages. Are you worried about cost? stability? timing?

linearity and cost, but thinking about it, this doesn't affect the response of the circuit as a whole that much.

You need to validate the reasons why a voltage divider is not a good choice. Base your design decision on facts, not on opinions. To help us help you, please [edit] your question to add these reasons.

Easiest is either a voltage divider or a voltage divider with a unity-gain buffer. You might prefer the latter if you want to reduce the loading on the 12V line and if your ADC needs a relatively low input impedance.
For example, if your ADC is okay with 2.5kΩ (most on-chip SAR ADCs present in MCUs) you could use a 10kΩ + 2.49kΩ voltage divider which would make your 3.3V ADC range 0..16.5V  - you can adjust the ratio to accommodate the maximum possible voltage on the 12V line. That will draw about 1mA at 12V from the supply.
Or you could use 1MΩ + 249kΩ and a CMOS-input unity gain buffer. You'll get a bit more error, more power consumption and have to consider op-amp saturation with the latter approach.
Here's a slight variation on the latter approach that uses the popular and inexpensive Microchip MCP601 op-amp:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I've given the op-amp a gain of 2 because the output is R-R but the inputs are not (though they do include ground in their range). That's not quite optimal from the pov of minimizing error, but it's only one part value on the BOM. You could also make R1, R2, R3 all 130kΩ, or adjust R4 for the range and make them all 100kΩ.

Using a voltage divider to scale 12V into 3.3V is absolutely ok. You should be able to feed the divider output directly to the microcontroller ADC input.
You didn’t ask, but I’ll mention that Analog Devices makes a high side sensing amplifier that’s perfect for measuring current, should you later decide that it matters to you. Check it out here: https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt6105.html

The test will be done on the voltage rail without load.
